# High latency on Amazon S3's getObject from a Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm using a lambda function to serve png files stored in an Amazon S3 bucket. I need those to be pulled relatively quickly (<300ms) for user experience reasons.

The issue I have is getting a single small (<100kb) object from my Amazon S3 bucket takes 300ms+ every single time

My code is quite basic:

```
def loadS3Object(key):
    bucket = 'bucketname' 
    s3=boto3.client('s3')
    http=urllib3.PoolManager()
    try:
        myObject = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    except ClientError as e:
        return False
```

1. Is there a way to reduce latency?
2. Or should I use something else than S3 for such a latency-sensitive need?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Increase the Lambda memory and thus performance available to the function. What are you doing in the Lambda function? Can you use presigned-URLs to not download the image in Lambda and have the client directly pull it from S3?

Comment: How is this code being invoked? Is it via API Gateway? What do you mean by "serve" files?

Comment: Would it make sense to use the S3 bucket as an origin for a cloudfront distribution?

Comment: @John - API Gateway. "Serves" mean sending the image back through HTTP. 

@ Maurice - increasing memory reduced 300ms to 30ms. Surprisingly, my hypothesis that it was an S3<->Lambda latency issue was wrong. The stupid reason was just the allocated memory/CPU.